# Hot reload in Xamarin Forms with genymotion not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, genymotion, hot-reload

I'm  trying to configure [HotReload](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload) 1.4.15 in VS 2017 for execute in genymotion emulator (Win 10). [Xamarin Live Reload - Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload&ssr=false#overview) installed. Variable path configured for all users:

[image]

In app.xaml.cs

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
#if DEBUG
            HotReloader.Current.Run(this);
#endif
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
```

// second try

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
#if DEBUG
        HotReloader.Current.Run(this, new HotReloader.Configuration
        {
            DeviceUrlPort = 15000
        });
        //HotReloader.Current.Run(this);
#endif
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

[image]

VS -> TOOLS -> ANDROID -> PROMPT ANDROID 
adb forward tcp:15000 tcp:15000
[image]

without success...

Whats can I missing? No exception, no error message, nothing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post an issue : https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload/issues

Comment: ty, @SushiHangover, Im following this: https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload/issues/1, waiting...